# Symfony KNP Snappy Bundle: The process has been signaled with signal "11"

Tags: symfony, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I created a PDF with a highcharts chart on it using KNP snappy bundle. If I do getOutputFromHtml(), rendering the twig file without the highcharts chart, it is successful. If I copy and paste an example from highcharts and then getOutputFromHtml(), it is successful. So it is not the path to WKHTMLTOPDF, highcharts, or the javascript causing the issue. If I switch out the example from highcharts with the chart I want to go there, then it throws an error of 'The process has been signaled with signal "11".'. I have the chart on other pages on the site and it does not throw any javascript errors, so it is not the chart. If I look at the html render from the twig file before getOutputFromHtml(), the chart is showing and does not throw any javascript errors. I have animation, enable mouse tracking, and shadow all set to false. The process error only goes away if I shorten the names on the data series or change the y on the last item in the data series. I have looked at other questions with the same error, but none of them solved my problem. I also verified that selinux was not causing the issue.

This is the chart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Highcharts.chart('tam-by-product-type-chart', {
                credits:{
                    enabled:false
                },
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'TAM by Product Type'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                accessibility: {
                    point: {
                        valueSuffix: '%'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Share',
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    animation: false,
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Addressable Wire/Cable',
                        y: {{ data.totalProductTypes.wireCable|number_format(2) }}
                    }, {
                        name: 'Addressable Lighting',
                        y: {{ data.totalProductTypes.lighting|number_format(2) }}
                    }, {
                        name: 'ACRF',
                        y: {{ data.totalProductTypes.conduitRacewayFittings|number_format(2) }}
                    }, {
                        name: 'ADSCB',
                        y: {{ data.totalProductTypes.distributionSwitchgearCircuitBreakers|number_format(2) }}
                    }, {
                        name: 'AIC',
                        y: {{ data.totalProductTypes.industrialControls|number_format(2) }}
                    }, {
                        name: 'All Other',
                        y: {{ data.totalProductTypes.other|number_format(2) }}
                    }]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is where I am making the pdf

```
$bodyHtml = $this->templating->render('pdf/reports/territory_book/body.html.twig', array('data' => $data));

$bodyPdf = $this->pdf->getOutputFromHtml($bodyHtml, array(
    'page-size' => 'Letter',
    'images' => true,
    'enable-javascript' => true,
    'javascript-delay' => 5000
));
```

Comment: Hi @Chelsea, So the problem is probably caused by your data. What are the example values of `y` property?

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for responding! it's not the data. This chart with the same data is displayed on other pages without error. If I use the example data, I still get the process 11 error because if the series data name.

Comment: Please try to define the data in a different way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4906/

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the font size on the chart. I reduced the font size to 5 and it produced the pdf without error.

```
dataLabels: {
     style: {
          fontSize: 5
     }
},
```